# Why this Android view doesn't fill the screen vertically?

Tags: android, view

Having this XML view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/myScrollLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/widget29"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/lstView1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        </ListView>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

[alt text http://img528.imageshack.us/img528/3603/ss3v.jpg](http://img528.imageshack.us/img528/3603/ss3v.jpg)

Why my ListView shows only the first item and does not fill the screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not put a `ListView` inside of a `ScrollView`. `ListView` already knows how to scroll.